# Hibernate validation property path for validation List with JSR-308

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator

I have following code:

```
public class ReferEmailForm {
    @Valid
    @NotEmpty
    private Set<@TypedEmail String> emails;

    ...
}
```

For some reason error from `@TypedEmail` in `BindingResult` is notified as attached to `emails[]` field. Is there any option to override this name? I need this to be able to use `<form:errors path="emails" />` in jsp. Current solution don't generate error message on form unfortunately.

Comment: Why do you have a `path="email"` while the field is `"emails"`??

Comment: Sorry that a typo. I have `emails` of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for answer everywhere I just noticed how stupid mistake I did. Hibernate is resolving variable name as `emails[]` because Set do not have index based access. After changing type to `List` it returns `emails[0]` which is way better.